# Regex match all except groups of characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match the following strings:

```
PHANTOGRAM • CUT / COPY • AB$SID 3 • FITZ & THE TANTRUMS
PHANTOGRAM,CUT / COPY,AB$SID 3,FITZ & THE TANTRUMS
PHANTOGRAM CUT / COPY AB$SID 3 FITZ & THE TANTRUMS
```

So, basically regex that matches anything between `( • |,|  |\n)`.

I have tried things like `(([^•\n])+)` and positive lookahead, but geez I can't for the life of me put it together. Any advice? My hunch is I need a combination of positive lookahead and negative lookahead.

Last note: this is for the **javascript** environment.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: And why doesn't your way work?

Comment: Can you show your attempted code?

Comment: Match *what* in the following strings?  The whole string?

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski, I'm trying to match the indvidual bands listed between the delimeters.

Answer (score 2):

Split should help you:

```
var str = "PHANTOGRAM • CUT / COPY • AB$SID 3 • FITZ & THE TANTRUMS";
var res = str.split("•|,| |\n");
```

Comment: Thanks! This was close but not quite there. I modified it to be a bit more robust (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using something similar to laune's example that worked well:

```
var matches = rawText.split(new RegExp(['\n', '•'].join('|'), 'g'));
```

Comment: Not quite the same delimiters you had in your original post, but OK.

Comment: Ah, yes, it is missing a couple but the gist is there. =)